# Mongoose is not returning all fields in the document using a simple find()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the following Schema:

```
let User = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  templates: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'TemplateInstance',
    required: false
  }
},{
  collection: 'users',
  timestamps: true
});
```

And the following Mongoose code:

```
exports.getUsers = (req, res) => {
  User.find((err, users) => {
    if(err)
      return res.status(400).json( { 'users_get_all': 'failure', 'err': err } );
    return res.status(200).json( { 'users_get_all': 'success', 'users': users } );
  });
};
```

Initially, each user Document does not have anything in the 'templates' field because after the user creates their account, that's when they get to attach templates to it. I have manually added some Template ObjectIDs to the 'templates' field of some users but when I run the getUsers() function, the user documents are returned but with no 'templates' field:

```
{"users_get_all":"success","users":[{"_id":"5b39f9da294d041b58f97cb3","email":"testemail@email.com","password":"password","firstName":"firstName","lastName":"lastName","createdAt":"2018-07-02T10:09:30.400Z","updatedAt":"2018-07-02T10:21:34.579Z","__v":0},{"_id":"5b39ff5723d93c17bc00eabf","email":"testemail2@email.com","password":"password","firstName":"firstName2","lastName":"lastName2","createdAt":"2018-07-02T10:32:55.308Z","updatedAt":"2018-07-02T10:32:55.308Z","__v":0}]}
```

If I look at the MongoDB in something like Studio 3T, the templates array definitely has ObjectIDs in it that refer to Templates in the Template collection.

[image: Screenshot of Studio 3T showing Users collection]

Any idea why the 'templates' field is not being returned?

Comment: in Schema you are delaring "templates" as object and in DB you have array.
Can you post JSON of the database?

Comment: Datatype missmatch is your problem.

Comment: Is it working??

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you are correct, I've got it working now and said your answer is right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your schema as follows:

```
let User = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  templates: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'TemplateInstance',
    required: false
  }]
},{
  collection: 'users',
  timestamps: true
});
```

As in database, you have templates in the array and you were declaring it an object in the schema.

Comment: Aah oh god, I did that in another Schema too a couple of days ago...thanks so much, I was banging my head against the wall.

Comment: What is weird though is that the function that did the findByIdAndUpdate() wasn't throwing an error...it was saying that the $push to the 'templates' array was successful whenever I did it and it did get added to the templates field of the collection as an array element. Strange. But thank you for the help!