# Mongoose array in document does not exist when queried

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I need to query for all documents with an array but the returned documents dont have the array.

query

```
(async () => {
        const data = await Lesson.find({signed: {$exists: true}});
        console.log(data[0].signed); # undefined
})();
```

model

```
const lessonSchema = new mon.Schema(
    {
        day: Number,
        startTime: Number,
        endTime: Number,
        description: {type: String, trim: true},
        signed: [mon.Schema.Types.ObjectId]
    }, 
    {
        collection: 'lessons'
    }
);
module.exports = mon.model("Lesson", lessonSchema);
```

I checked the database and the documents do have the array.
The query retrieve **everything** except for the array (all of the documents and their values except for the array).
NOTE: in the database I have only two test documents. both have an array and both don't have the array in the query.

Thanks

**EDIT:** I found out that if I remove the signed property from the schema it works. Why?

Comment: Have you try findOne function ?

Comment: `$exists` matches the documents that contain the field, including documents where the field value is null, have you checked all documents in `data` or just `data[0]`?

Comment: @sinabariaji yes. in the db there are two test documents with the array

Comment: in the returned query both dont have the array but they should have

Comment: @Konflex I need all of the documents not only one. in the code I only used one as an example.

Comment: Solution can be found in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51134236/mongoose-is-not-returning-all-fields-in-the-document-using-a-simple-find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem because the type of signed was objectId and the ids I used were strings. I cleared the array and added real ObjectId and it worked.